# How to create a shapely Polygon from a list of shapely Points?

Tags: python, polygon, shapely

I want to create a polygon from shapely points.

```
from shapely import geometry
p1 = geometry.Point(0,0)
p2 = geometry.Point(1,0)
p3 = geometry.Point(1,1)
p4 = geometry.Point(0,1)

pointList = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p1]

poly = geometry.Polygon(pointList)
```

gives me an type error `TypeError: object of type 'Point' has no len()`

How to create a `Polygon` from shapely `Point` objects?

Comment: I submitted an issue on GitHub regarding this: [Inconsistency in creating collections with a sequence of Point's](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/706). They say it's a bug to be fixed.

Comment: This question is outdated; it does not produce an error anymore.  See Adam's answer.

Comment: With Shapely 2.0, this raises: `ValueError: Inconsistent coordinate dimensionality`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

If you specifically want to construct your Polygon from the shapely geometry Points, then call their x, y properties in a list comprehension. In other words:

```
from shapely import geometry

poly = geometry.Polygon([[p.x, p.y] for p in pointList])

print(poly.wkt)  # prints: 'POLYGON ((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))'
```

Note that shapely is clever enough to close the polygon on your behalf, i.e. you don't necessarily have to pass-in the first point again at the end.

Comment: for me it works like   poly = Polygon([[p[0].x, p[0].y] for p in pointList])

Comment: Sounds like you have nested points (multipoint?) or a line instead?

Comment: @songololo how can it know how to close the polygon if it only has one x, y location? How does it know how big it is? Is there a way to pass x1, y1, x2, y2 coordinates instead?

Answer (score 25):

A [`Polygon`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#polygons) object requires a nested list of numbers, not a list of `Point` objects.

```
polygon = Polygon([[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 11):

In version `1.7a2` they have fixed this.

The code in question will just work.

[Link to CHANGES.txt](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/803b21bb87f3f76ce25bec4e015b46038c0df1f4/CHANGES.txt#L25)

Answer (score 4):

The `Polygon` constructor doesn't expect a list of `Point` objects but a list of point coordinates.

See https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#polygons

Comment: This answer became outdated and is no longer true - see Adam's answer

Answer (score -2):

You could just do that instead:

```
p1 = geometry.Point(0,0)
p2 = geometry.Point(1,0)
p3 = geometry.Point(1,1)
p4 = geometry.Point(0,1)

pointList = [p1, p2, p3, p4]
poly = geometry.Polygon([i for i in pointList])
```