# How to connect points to create a polygon

Tags: python, polygon, point, shapely

I want to connect a set of points to create a polygon. I tried connecting points clockwise, but did not receive the expected results.
Could anyone suggest how to improve the code so that I could get the proper result or what other methods I would use to connect the point

My points coordinates:

```
[<POINT (435099.004 121451.158)>,
 <POINT (435109.204 121451.579)>,
 <POINT (435099.604 121441.77)>,
 <POINT (435128.704 121459.57)>,
 <POINT (435120.604 121452.07)>,
 <POINT (435121.204 121442.37)>,
 <POINT (435128.904 121450.87)>,
 <POINT (435109.104 121441.67)>,
 <POINT (435120.954 121450.67)>,
 <POINT (435111.204 121451.668)>,
 <POINT (435120.204 121459.27)>,
 <POINT (435109.204 121449.27)>,
 <POINT (435111.204 121449.27)>]
```

###### Approach connecting points clockwise:

```
def calculate_angle(p1, p2):
return math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x)

def find_lowest_point(points):
lowest_point = min(points, key=lambda p: (p.x, p.y))
return lowest_point

enter def connect_points_clockwise(points):
lowest_point = find_lowest_point(points)
sorted_points = sorted(points, key=lambda p: calculate_angle(lowest_point, p))

connected_points = []
for i in range(len(sorted_points)):
    start_point = sorted_points[i]
    end_point = sorted_points[(i + 1) % len(sorted_points)]
    connected_points.append((start_point, end_point))

def connect_points_clockwise(points):
lowest_point = find_lowest_point(points)
sorted_points = sorted(points, key=lambda p: calculate_angle(lowest_point, p))

connected_points = []
for i in range(len(sorted_points)):
    start_point = sorted_points[i]
    end_point = sorted_points[(i + 1) % len(sorted_points)]
    connected_points.append((start_point, end_point))

return connected_points

def display_polygon(points):
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()

# Extract x and y coordinates from points
x_coords = [p.x for p in points]
y_coords = [p.y for p in points]

# Create a Polygon patch
#polygon = Polygon([(p.x, p.y) for p in points], fill=None)
#ax.add_patch(polygon)

# Plot points with numbers
for i, p in enumerate(points):
    plt.text(p.x, p.y, str(i + 1), fontsize=12, ha='center', va='center', color='red')

# Plot points
plt.plot(x_coords, y_coords, 'bo')

plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.title('Polygon from Points')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()

# Connect points clockwise
connected_points = connect_points_clockwise(new_points)
```

Results is presented in Figure Polygon_from_points [image]

And the polygon I would like to generate should align with what is presented in Figure outline_34
[image]

Comment: Please edit your code block: the indentation has been messed up and the method `connect_points_clockwise` appears twice.

Comment: If your question is only related to converting a list of points into a polygon, this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457089/how-to-create-a-shapely-polygon-from-a-list-of-shapely-points. If not, you should probably rephrase your title and your question.